# Add static column inside foreach binding in knockout

Tags: dynamic, knockout.js

I have the following table with knockout bindings:

```
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr data-bind="foreach: ActiveHeaders">
            <td>
                <input type="text" data-bind="value: $root.dynamicFilter(Filter), valueUpdate: 'afterkeyup', returnAction:$root.filterData" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr data-bind="foreach: ActiveHeaders">
            <th>
                <a style="cursor:pointer" data-bind="text:Filter, click: function(data){$root.loadArticles('1',Filter, data)}"></a>
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="articleListing" data-bind="foreach: Articles">
        <tr data-bind="foreach: $parent.columnNames">
            <td>
                <span data-bind="text:  $parent[$data], event: { dblclick: function(data,event){ $root.editField($parent, data, event)}}"></span>
                <input type="text" class="thVal" data-bind="value:  $parent[$data]" style="display:none;" />
            </td>                
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I am binding the columns dynamically(number of columns is not known) which are configured by the user. I want to add a static column as the last column in the table which will have a `Delete` button and no header and is bound to the `Articles` object in the `<tbody foreach>` binding, which on clicking will call a method and will delete that record in db through an ajax call. I want to do something like this:

```
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr data-bind="foreach: ActiveHeaders">
            <td>
                <input type="text" data-bind="value: $root.dynamicFilter(Filter), valueUpdate: 'afterkeyup', returnAction:$root.filterData" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr data-bind="foreach: ActiveHeaders">
            <th>
                <a style="cursor:pointer" data-bind="text:Filter, click: function(data){$root.loadArticles('1',Filter, data)}"></a>
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="articleListing" data-bind="foreach: Articles">
        <tr data-bind="foreach: $parent.columnNames">
            <td>
                <span data-bind="text:  $parent[$data], event: { dblclick: function(data,event){ $root.editField($parent, data, event)}}"></span>
                <input type="text" class="thVal" data-bind="value:  $parent[$data]" style="display:none;" />
            </td>       
            <td>
               <input type="button" value="Delete" data-bind="click: $root.deleteArticle" />
            </td>         
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

How can I do this when binding columns dynamically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use containerless control flow syntax, which is based on comment tags. You can read details [here](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/foreach-binding.html). Something like this:

```
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <!-- ko foreach: ActiveHeaders -->
                <th>
                    <input type="text" data-bind="value: $root.dynamicFilter(Filter), valueUpdate: 'afterkeyup', returnAction:$root.filterData" />
                </th>
            <!-- /ko -->
            <th>
                Fixed
            </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <!-- ko foreach: ActiveHeaders -->
                <th>
                    <a style="cursor:pointer" data-bind="text:Filter, click: function(data){$root.loadArticles('1',Filter, data)}"></a>
                </th>
            <!-- /ko -->
            <th>
                Fixed
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="articleListing" data-bind="foreach: Articles">
        <tr>
            <!-- ko foreach: $parent.columnNames -->
            <td>
                <span data-bind="text:  $parent[$data], event: { dblclick: function(data,event){ $root.editField($parent, data, event)}}"></span>
                <input type="text" class="thVal" data-bind="value:  $parent[$data]" style="display:none;" />
            </td>      
            <!-- /ko -->
            <td>
               <input type="button" value="Delete" data-bind="click: $root.deleteArticle" />
            </td>         
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I am still new to KO, but this works perfectly, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I believe that it's as simple as adding the whole fixed column at the end of each column array of your articles.

Or you can add the whole column in your item template and bind <kbd>Delete</kbd> to view model's root (i.e. `click: $root.removeArticle.bind(this)`, and note that `removeArticle` uses `bind(...)` so `this` will be the article!).

Comment: Can you give an example please?

Comment: @seadrag0n Now I'm Bruce Lee and I'll tell you: *use your mind, be formless...*. Try it yourself, I believe my answer gives you a precious hint if you know how to work with Knockout. If you don't understand some part of my answer, I'll be glad to add more detail, but don't ask me to give you the final result :D

Comment: I understood what you were trying to say but I am learning Knockout since 3 weeks and don't know much, but I will keep in mind about Trying it myself. Thanks!